# Find all lines that match regex pattern and grab part of string

Tags: python, regex

```
f = open("machinelist.txt", 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
for host in lines:
       hostnames = host.strip()
       print hostnames
```

Returns:

```
\\TESTHOSTDEV01
\\TESTHOSTDEVDB01
\\TESTHOSTDEVDBQA
\\TESTHOSTDEVQA02
\\BTLCMOODY01          MRA Server
\\BTLCSTG05            StG Server
\\BTLCWEB02
\\BTLCWSUS01           Test Update Server
\\HIMSAPP01
\\SLVAPP01
\\TORAAPP01
\\HNSVAPP01
\\TESAPP01
```

I am curious if there is a way to use re.findall() to grab all lines that begin with "\" however I just want to capture return the hostnames, not the "\ or the comments after the host such as "MRA Server" (example: BTLCMOODY01)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach using regular expression:

```
import re

f = open("machinelist.txt", 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
for host in lines:
    hostnames = host.strip()
    if hostnames.startswith('\\'):
        print(re.match(r'\\\\(\S+)',hostnames).group(1))
```

It yields:

```
TESTHOSTDEV01
TESTHOSTDEVDB01
TESTHOSTDEVDBQA
TESTHOSTDEVQA02
BTLCMOODY01
BTLCSTG05
BTLCWEB02
BTLCWSUS01
HIMSAPP01
SLVAPP01
TORAAPP01
HNSVAPP01
TESAPP01
```

Comment: Ah Birei, I think get it now. group(1) would be any string of characters but that ofcourse would be the (\S+) after "\\\\"

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this(no need of regex):

Use `str.startswith` to check if a line starts with `'\\'`:

```
>>> strs = "\\BTLCMOODY01          MRA Server\n"
>>> strs.startswith('\\')
True
```

Then use a combination of `str.split` and `str.lstrip` to get the first word:

```
>>> strs.split(None, 1)
['\\BTLCMOODY01', 'MRA Server\n']  
#apply str.lstrip on the first item
>>> strs.split(None, 1)[0].lstrip('\\')
'BTLCMOODY01'
```

**Code:**

```
>>> with open('abc1') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         if line.startswith('\\'):     #check if the line startswith `\`
...             print line.split(None,1)[0].lstrip('\\') 
...             
TESTHOSTDEV01
TESTHOSTDEVDB01
TESTHOSTDEVDBQA
TESTHOSTDEVQA02
BTLCMOODY01
BTLCSTG05
BTLCWEB02
BTLCWSUS01
HIMSAPP01
SLVAPP01
TORAAPP01
HNSVAPP01
TESAPP01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"\\([a-z]+)[\s]+",re.I) # single-slash, foll'd by word: \HOSTNAME  

fh = open("file.txt","r")

for x in fh:
    match = re.search(pattern,x)
    if(match): print(match.group(1))
```

Comment: Don't use `file.readlines`(loads everything into memory), you can iterate over the file object itself.